# Change script in preprocess

Tags: 7, javascript, theming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update jQuery to the latest version I can download?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download)

I need to upgrade jQuery from 1.5 to 1.7 in Drupal 7.

In Drupal 6 I could implement a `hook_preprocess_html()` function and alter the `$variables['scripts']` to do this; but after inspecting `$variables` in Drupal 7, I can see there is no index called `'scripts'`.

How can I do the same thing in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it use [hook_js_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_js_alter/7). But unless you really know what you're doing, consider using [jquery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good Idea to change manually the jQuery lib of drupal , because It can cause lot of bugs , instead of this use [jquery update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module