# jQuery Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Tags: 7, javascript

I downloaded a jQuery Lightbox2 library (not module, just a raw library) and added the following in my custom module:

```
drupal_add_js($libpath . '/js/jquery-ui-1.8.18.custom.min.js');
drupal_add_js($libpath . '/js/jquery.smooth-scroll.min.js');
drupal_add_js($libpath . '/js/lightbox.js');
```

But it causes an error like this (see below debug printscreen):

[image]

Could someone tell me, what to do to get rid of the error?

After some googling I installed the JQuery Dollar module but the error is still there.  No clue what else to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was only added in jQuery v1.7; Drupal 7 ships with jQuery v1.4, and can be updated to 1.5 using the [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. The reason you're getting the error is simply that the lightbox library you're using is written for jQuery v1.7 and above.

See [How do I update jQuery to the latest version I can download?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download) for some ideas on how to get round this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to improve compatibility with other javascript frameworks, Drupal 7 requires to use a wrapper. Instead of `$(document)` in Drupal 6 it would be `jQuery(document)` in Drupal 7 (there are more options though).

Since you are not using the Lightbox2 module but just an external script it might not play along well. Although, I would rather expect the `$ is not a function` error message.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 'on' function is a cousin of 'delegate', and was implemented in jQuery 1.7. Which version of jQuery are you using with your Drupal?

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to do it.  Install this module:

https://drupal.org/project/jquery_plugin

Then add the following to your template.php:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_html(&$variables){
  drupal_add_library('jquery_plugin', 'tooltip');
}
```

And then you are free to add whatever javascript you want to your site as far as tooltip is concerned.