# Remove jquery script

Tags: 7, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I update jQuery to the latest version I can download?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download)

In Firefox I get an unresponsive script error from Google hosted jquery but can't echo the problem on other browsers.

I just looked at the source of drupal and it's loading v1.4 of jquery automatically. I applied my own Google Hosted link to jquery v1.8 in html.tpl.php so in  the page is loading 2 versions of jQuery.

I think this could be the reason for the crash. In any case, I still want to remove the redundant script.

How would I go about removing the the automatically added jquery script? I want to print $scripts as some modules have dependents there.

Comment: No i don't want to update Drupal jquery. I want to use google hosted jquery so I want to remove core's output of jquery script in the header.

Comment: Make sure you read the linked answer fully, it'll tell you how to remove the core jquery files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of jQuery.
>
> Updates:
>
> - Drupal 5 to jQuery 1.2.6
> - Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2
> - Drupal 7 to jQuery 1.5.x, 1.7.x, 1.8.x, 1.9.x, 1.10.x and jQuery UI 1.10.2
> - Drupal 8: TBD