# How to update to jQuery v1.11.1?

Tags: javascript, cdn

I'm trying to implement a full screen bootstrap carousel base on this [tutorial](http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/2/understanding-responsive-bootstrap-3-carousel-tutorial). He mention to use the jQuery version 1.11.1. And I was wondering what is the best way to upgrade to this version. I'm currently using the [jquery_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module but this module does not have the ability to upgrade to jQuery version 1.11.1.

I believe that I can use the CDN by pasting the below code in the my page template.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I'm looking for the best practice to insert this jQuery version 1.11.1 on my Drupal site ?

In 2012 a similar question was ask ["How do I update jQuery to the latest version I can download?"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28820/how-do-i-update-jquery-to-the-latest-version-i-can-download) and one of the solution was to use the module [jQuery Multi] to have different version of jQuery.[4](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti)

Anyway what it the best method to update jQuery v1.11.1 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way is to use install [jQuery Update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update), which gives you the option to use new version of jQuery.

- Download the jQuery Update mobile and extract it into sites/all/modules
- Go to modules and enable the jQuery Update model
- Visit `http://mysite/admin/config/development/jquery_update` to select which version would you like to use

You can also use [jQuery Multi module](https://www.drupal.org/project/jqmulti) to update the jQuery module, the installation process is same as jQuery Update.

Answer (score 4):

Use the module [Jquery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update):

> Upgrades the version of jQuery in Drupal core to a newer version of
>   jQuery.

For 1.11, I believe you will need to use the DEV version, and take a look at [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/2197249) item in the Issue Queue for updating to that version.

Comment: I think you answer is better because question is about how use jquery 1.11, vote up