# How to update jquery version without hacking or updating the core?

Tags: 8

I am trying to upgrade my the core/jquery library from 3.2 to 3.4.1 in the core.

How can I update the assets/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js defined in core.libraries.yml to a further jquery version?

I can not currently update my drupal to v8.9, which comes with v3.5 of jQuery.

I am using drupal 8.6

So far I have tried looking at [How to update to jQuery v1.11.1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/128966/how-to-update-to-jquery-v1-11-1) but the recommended module doesn't seem to be available for drupal 8 and above.

Comment: You can overwrite JS files in from any module, even core, take a look here: [Override a single JavaScript file from a module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/200418/override-a-single-javascript-file-from-a-module)

Comment: That helped. Thanks @Hudri